TailwindCSS not working in React Native project
I created a React Native app using Expo and tried to use Tailwind CSS with the help of NativeWind. I followed this docs:
Read the docs here...
Versions:

react-native : 0.74.3
nativewind: 2.0.11
typescript: 5.3.3
tailwindcss: 3.3.2

tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};

babel.config.js:
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      ["nativewind/babel",{mode : "compileOnly"}]
    ],
  };
};

After this, I got a red line in my code while using className indicating an error which was solved by creating a file named my-app.d.ts.
/// <reference types="nativewind/types" />

index.tsx:
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Link } from 'expo-router'

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-white">
            <Text className="text-3xl">Hello! I am starting from Home</Text>
            <StatusBar style='auto' />
            <Link href="/profile" style={{color : 'blue'}}>Go To Profile</Link>
        </View>
    )
}

The Tailwind classes in <View> are not working.
I tried:

Restarting the server again.
Start using --clear
npm run start --clear


Is index.tsx under one of the paths you defined in
content: ["./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],?

yeah! It's inside the app folder.

Is it directly under app folder? Or within a sub folder. Your current settings needs to include "./app/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}" if it is directly under app folder.

Which expo version are you using?

install and use twrnc
import tw from 'twrnc';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Link } from 'expo-router'

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View style={tw`flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-white`}>
            <Text style={tw`text-3xl`}>Hello! I am starting from Home</Text>
            <StatusBar style='auto' />
            <Link href="/profile" style={{color : 'blue'}}>Go To Profile</Link>
        </View>
    )
}


yeah! I belive we have other methods and I have used them. But I specifically want to do with react native and find out the problem as we cannot say that let's use twrnc while working in a company.

I encountered the same problem, I installed nativewind version 2.0.0, and the problem was solved
Good luck

I write custom function to do that without need of installing 3rd packages, it should:

Convert styles from string or array of string. The input string should follows Tailwindcss style
Return style in ViewProps, TextProps...

const APP_STYLES = StyleSheet.create({
  justifyCenter: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  itemsCenter: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  ...
})

type StyleName = keyof typeof APP_STYLES

const styleReturnString: Record<string, <T extends string>(value: T) => any> = {
  bg: (val) => ({
    backgroundColor: val
  } as Record<keyof ViewStyle, any>),
  ...
}

type SpecialTemplateTypeString = `${keyof typeof styleReturnString}[${string}]`

function styled(...styleNames: (StyleName | SpecialTemplateTypeString | '' | undefined)[]): [StyleProp<any>] {
  try {

    return styleNames.filter(Boolean).map(styleName => {
      if (!styleName?.includes('[')) {
        return APP_STYLES[styleName as StyleName]
      } else {
        const [style, variable] = styleName.split('[')
        return styleReturnString[style as keyof typeof styleReturnString](variable.replaceAll(/[\[\]]/g, ''))
      }
    }) as [StyleProp<any>]

  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Error in styled: ${styleNames}`)
  }
}

Then you can simply use this function replace style in View, Text... component like this:
<View style={styled("bg[red]", "flex", "justifyCenter")}></View>

This is simple idea, you can improved it, eg: wrap by another function to join the array to string...
